# Way to store large amount of experiments and corresponding results

Tags: database

I have an experiment setup that produces a few csv and text files every run.  In my research I run a number of these in parallel each day and trying to store and organized them in a directory heir-achy is getting rather inefficient and tedious.

One idea I thought of doing was using MySQL or something to store the the run description along with the associated output.  This however has the inefficiency in that I am storing a number of gigantic Strings in the table fields.

Basically I would like to know if a system exists that can automatically organize the output of runs.  Such that it would give a list of the run descriptions, and upon choosing this you can request the corresponding outputs.  This wouldn't have to be in any particular language as I can hopefully just add the step to a shell script.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I am not sure the data itself is important.  The CSV file is simply a formatted output I can easily read into a spread sheet or do further parsing on.  An example line would be: String, float, float

Comment: There are also three to four text files printed out that would need their formatting kept.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the csv and txt files are identically named for each run minus the extensions. Have you considered a simple java or python script that could take all of the csv and txt files in a folder and put them into a single XML file where all of the information would be saved and with the data from the linked csv file and txt file together, meaning that for hundreds of file pairs (csv and txt) you could end up with a single XML file that could be opened to see the separate run results?

Comment: I like that idea.  That would enable linking of a description, input,and outputs.  The issues here would be the xml file would quickly get rather large and hard to read through. Though I could probably build something to handle it when that happens. The second issue would be preventing concurrent writing to a single file.  The parallel processes are all happening on separate vms.  I was planning on having them all submit their results to another server for storage.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of having all of your data files for a certain number of runs, say 1000, saved to a temporary folder. After that number of runs, pause, push all the data files into a single XML file and move it some where else, clear the temp folder and start again. XML files I believe can be open easily in Excel 2007 or later, since the office 2007 file format is a Zipped XML structure. And Excel has the benefit of being programmed to handle files in the 10-100mb range, opposed to firefox/ie which are meant for kb level HTML/XML files.