# Tool for manipulating results of large set of computational experiments

Tags: pivot-table

I am a researcher and my primary interest is improving sparse kernels for high performance computing. I investigate large number of parameters on many sparse matrices. I wonder whether there is a tool to manage these results. The problems that I encounter are:

1. Combine results of several experiments for each matrix
2. Version the results
3. Taking average, finding minimum/maximum/standard deviation of results
4. There are hundreds of metrics that describe the performance improvement. I want to select a couple of the metrics easily and try to find which metric correlates with the performance improvement.

Here I gave a sample small instance of my huge problem. There are three types of parameters and two values for each parameter: Row/Column, Cyclic/Block, HeuristicA/HeuristicB. So there must 8 files for the combination of these parameters. Contents of two of them:

Contents of the file `RowCyclicHeuristicA.txt`

```
a.mtx#3#5.1#10#2%#row#cyclic#heuristicA#1
a.mtx#7#4.1#10#4%#row#cyclic#heuristicA#2
b.mtx#4#6.1#10#3%#row#cyclic#heuristicA#1
b.mtx#12#5.7#10#7%#row#cyclic#heuristicA#2
b.mtx#9#3.1#10#10%#row#cyclic#heuristicA#3
```

Contents of the file `ColumnCyclicHeuristicA.txt`

```
a.mtx#3#5.1#10#5%#column#cyclic#heuristicA#1
a.mtx#1#5.3#10#6%#column#cyclic#heuristicA#2
b.mtx#4#7.1#10#5%#column#cyclic#heuristicA#1
b.mtx#3#5.7#10#9%#column#cyclic#heuristicA#2
b.mtx#5#4.1#10#3%#column#cyclic#heuristicA#3
```

I have a scheme file to describe the contents of these files. This file has a line describing type and meaning of each column in the result files:

```
str MatrixName
int Speedup
double Time
int RepetationCount
double Imbalance
str Parameter1
str Parameter2
str Parameter3
int ExperimentId
```

I need to display **average** `Time` and two types of parameters as follows: (numbers in the following table are random)

```
            Parameter1    Parameter2
Matrix      row    col    cyclic   block
 a.mtx      4.3    5.2    4.2      5.4
 b.mtx      2.1    6.3    8.4      3.3
```

Is there an advanced and sophisticated tool that gets the scheme of the table above and generates this table automatically? Currently I have a tool written in Java to process raw files and Latex code to manipulate and display the table using `pgfplotstable`. However, I need one tool that is more professional. I do not want pivot tables of MS Excel.

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198152/way-to-store-large-amount-of-experiments-and-corresponding-results).

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating large amounts of data in an unknown format is...challenging for a generic program. Your best bet is probably similar to what you're doing already. Use a custom program to reformat your results into something easier to handle (*backend*), and a visualisation program of your choice to let you view and play around with the data (*frontend*).

**Backend**

For your problem I'd suggest a relational database (e.g.[Mysql](http://www.mysql.com/%20MySQL)). Has a longer setup time than other options, but if this is an ongoing problem it should be worthwhile, as it allows you to easily pull fields of interest.
`SELECT AVG(Speedup) FROM results WHERE Parameter1="column" AND Parameter2="cyclic"` for example. You'll then still need a simple script to insert your data in the first place, and then to pull the results of interest in a useful format you can stick into your viewer. Or if you so desire you can just run queries directly against the db.

Alternatively, what I usually use is just Python or Perl. Read in your data files, strip the data you don't want, rearrange into the desire structure, and write out to some standard format your frontend and use. Replace Python/Perl with the language of your choice.

**Frontend**

Personally, I almost always use Excel. The backend does most of the heavy lifting, so I get a csv file with the results I care about all nicely ordered already. Excel then lets me play around with the data, doing stuff like taking averages, plotting, reordering, etc fairly simply.

Other tools I use to display stuff which are probably not useful for you, but included for completeness include:

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) - Mostly machine learning targetted, but provides tools for searching for trends or correlations. Useful to play around with data looking for things of interest.

Python/IDL/etc - For when I need data that can't be represented by a spreadsheet. These programs can, in addition to doing the backend's job of extracting and bulk manipulations, generate difference images, complicated graphs, or whatever else I need.